# Does python close automatically opened file some times

Tags: python, file-handling

I am  using python 3.7 ( on windows 10 )
I execute following line on terminal.

```py
open('textfile.txt')
```

After I try to delete the file ('textfile.txt') then os said It is being used by some program.
I close the terminal and open a new terminal then I execute following code

```py
open('textfile.txt').read()
```

I try to delete the file ('textfile.txt') then It's deleted. 
My problem is both times I did't assign file object to any variable but first time file didn't close automatically second time It was happend.

Why second time python close the file automatically ?

Comment: Python interactive sessions always keep the result of the last expression around, bound to `_`.

Comment: @brunns Yep, that's it. To expand further, this means that when you just run `open(path)` and wait, then the file descriptor is stored in a variable, while `open(path).read()` binds the content of the file to a variable, but the file descriptor is not bound and can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

If you open a File, you have to close

```
f = open('textfile.txt')
f.close()
```

Or used pythonic way:

```
with open("textfile.txt") as f:
    d = f.read()
    #On exit with code indent it will close

print("Here the file is closed automatically")
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't answer the question. See the comments on the question

Comment: Yes, Thanks you ! but I have learnt those things I want to know what was happened